# Gauss lemma for arbitrary commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Part (iv) of exercise #2 for chapter 1 in Atiyah and Macdonald's book [Introduction to Commutative Algebra](https://books.google.com/books/abou/Introduction_To_Commutative_Algebra.html?id=HOASFid4x18C) asserts that if $f, g \in A[x]$ are primitive then $fg$ is primitive. We know that this is true when the coefficient ring $A$ is a UFD in which case it is the statement of Gauss' lemma. I have tried hard to show it for arbitrary ring as the problem says but did not manage to do that. So my question is: Though I do not doubt the author, is Gauss lemma really valid for arbitrary commutative rings with unity and can I have some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Assume the contrary and then reduce all data modulo a maximal ideal.